# Lebesgue Measure of a Function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

We have the notion of Lebesgue measure, which I generally think of as the length/area of some interval in the space considered. We also have the notion of Lebesgue measurable functions. I was wondering if there is some way to compute the Lebesgue measure of a function? Perhaps, for example the function $f(x)=\sin(x)$. The only thing that comes to my mind would be the arclength of the curve over some interval. Alternatively, can we describe the Lebesgue measure of a function as the length of the interval of the inverse image of the function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is the [pushforward measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure), is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say that a Lebesgue measure is a length/area of some sorts, then it seems you're thinking of original arguments being sets. That is $\lambda(A)$ should give some number, which you understand as a measure of $A$. In that case, your question "what is a Lebesgues measure of a function" to me immediately triggers the concept $\lambda(f)$ which is simply an integral: $\lambda(f) = \int f\,\mathrm d\lambda$.

Note that those two concepts are essentially the one. Namely, if you define (some) measure $\mu$ for sets, you can get its action on functions starting by approximating them with [simple functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_function). On the other hand, if you managed first to define $\mu$ for functions, then you get its actions on sets through the indicator functions: a measure of a set $A$ can be obtained by $\mu(1_A)$.

I would not say that a pushforward measure is a measure of a function, as it is rather a change of measure using a function (or a map in general).

Answer (score 1):

Recall that measurability of a function is not defined in the same way as measurability of a set. You define measurability of a function to be able to integrate it, and so your "measure" of $f$ would most naturally be its integral, while you define measurability of a set to be able to measure it using a measure. So if you want some notion of the measure of a function $f$ on some measure space $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$, the most natural notion would simply be

$$\int_X f\,\mathrm{d}\mu.$$

I'd also like to say that this makes a lot of sense if you look back at the basic definitions though simple functions, where you have

$$\int_X a_j\chi_{A_j}\,\mathrm{d}\mu=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\mu(A_j)$$

showing you even more explicitly how the function is "measured".